# I have problem with laravel policies..it doesn't work

Tags: php, laravel

This is my StorePolicy:

```
public function view(User $user, store $store)
{
   return true;
}
```

, this is my AuthServiceProvider:

```
protected $policies = [
   store::class => StorePolicy::class,
];
```

, this is my api.php file:

```
Route::group([ 'middleware' => ['auth:sanctum']],function () {
    Route::resources([
       'store' => StoreController::class,
    ]);
});
```

and this is my controller:

```
public function __construct()
{
   $this->authorizeResource(store::class, 'store');
}

public function show($id)
{
   echo 'hi :)';
}
```

this is my problem, when i check the route ('/store') get the result but when i check the route ('/store/1',.eg) i get 403 error. what should i do ? :(

it's strange, in index method of my controller when i check the below code i get correct result that i want and does it work.

```
public function index()
{
   $store = new store();
   $this->authorize('view', $store);
        
   $data = store::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->simplePaginate(10);
   return response([
      'data' => $data,
   ], 200);
}
```

Comment: Have a read of https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/22847#issuecomment-521308861 one point here is that `show($id)` needs to be `show(store $id)` for example

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
public function index(store $store)
{
```

Instead of

```
public function index()
{
   $store = new store();
```

Comment: thanks, but my problem is other methods than index. i get 403 error constantly.

Comment: make sure your passing the instance of store as second parameter to authorize, not collection or array or anything else. It should match the policy method signature.

Comment: I added the instance of store as second parameter to method show "show($id, store $store)", but i get the error Too few arguments to function App\\Http\\Controllers\\StoreController::show(). what should i do?

Comment: It means in controller now it's asking for second parameter:
$this->authorize('show', $store);